# Selenium Webdriver: Java: Code to verify that imported data is correct

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to selenium and java, in my project I have to import data in a table of 30 rows and 10 column on a web application through a file (xls or xml).

Now my issue is I have to verify that all the data imported correctly in each row and each column. Web page have pagination and in one go it only show 10 rows ..remaining data in next page.

My verification points are:
1) No data is available in table before import.
2) All data populated successfully in the table against each row and column.
3) When delete the data from 2,3 rows, only that data should remove from table.

Thanks in Advance
Amit

Comment: What you have tried? Can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

Without code specifics are difficult...

I would approach this by writing a function that will compare the app table with a table in memory.

1) Read the external file into memory. (add one bool flag column next to each that is false)
2) Navigate to section and upload the file via Selenium Code in the app.
3) Grab all elements from the app table object on the page.
4) Loop through the elements and compare against the memory table (toggle flag to true for each one)
5) Save non-matching data into a separate object.
6) Add anything that is still false on the in memory table to the non-matching object in step 5
7) Output the diff object in whatever format you want which you can easily see what didn't match up.

Other tweaks would probably need to be done to, but that really depends on the specifics of your application.  Personally I would avoid an actual DataTable memory object and use some list like object so I could utilize linq for efficiency...linq doesn't work for java though...